# How to fetch data from a server running on localhost in flutter?

Tags: python, api, flutter, localhost

I wrote an API in python and I'm running it on http://127.0.0.1:5000.
(Using Flask. Also, I'm currently running it on a development server for testing purposes)

But when I tried to get the response using the http package in Flutter, I got an XMLHttpRequest error.

```
void api() async {
  const String url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/dosomething?query=This doesn't work!"; # this is an example
  Response response = await get(url);
  print(response.body); # I'm printing this for testing
}
```

Note: I have checked the URL too, it works.

What could be the problem? And how to fix it?

Important - The following answers work when I try with an API running on the web (in this case, WorldTimeAPI). But, when I try with my code, it somehow doesn't work. Although it works perfectly fine when I manually test it.

This is a simplified version of my API code -

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/dosomething', methods = ['GET'])
def API():
     result = {}
     result['result'] = user_input = str(request.args['query'])
     return jsonify(result)
```

Comment: replace `void()` by `Future` and then try

Answer (score 1):

You have to first import this

> import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

then for API call pass your `HTTP` extension and then pass your body type like `post or get`

```
  Future api() async {
    const String url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/dosomething?query=This doesn't work!';
    Response response = await http.get(url);  // here i passed http.get
    print(response.body); // You should get your result
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm done checking. When I checked with an actual API (in this case WorldTimeAPI) it works. But when I try with my own API (running on localhost) it doesn't work. Can there be some problem with the API? (Although it works fine when I manually try it)

Comment: @AnshulRaj not sure, about your API maybe some problem in your API or in your data

Comment: I doubt that too, but if there is some problem with the API, then why does it work when I paste it in Chrome? Is using localhost the problem? Should I somehow set it up on the web and then try?

Comment: I tied postman. It works. But still why can't I do it directly?

Comment: When I am trying to use it now, flutter gives me an error : "The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'."

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what function get does, but use http like this:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http; //Import in the beginning of file

void api() async {
  const String url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/dosomething?query=This doesn't work!';
  var response = await http.get(url);
  print(response.body);
}
```

Comment: I've checked the code. When I checked with an actual API (in this case WorldTimeAPI) it works. But when I try with my own API (running on localhost) it doesn't work. Can there be some problem with the API? (Although it works fine when I manually try it)

Comment: What exactly does not work? Maybe you can send you API code.

Comment: You can check my code here - 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mYHfbtCG0lffJb3qg__w4vwIsvuumKBU?usp=sharing

Hope you can help, thanks

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly is not working? Is thrown any error or what?

Comment: The API seems to be working. So does the HTTP request. But somehow, it can't fetch the API response.

Comment: What exactly the request returns?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest error. I thought this was because of the API running on localhost. So, I uploaded it to pythonanywhere. But still, the same response. The API returns a JSON object.

Comment: The thing is that the API checks for profanity in the request and returns true or false accordingly. It also returns a sentiment analysis score.

Comment: That's probably OK, but what exactly does not work in Flutter? Please try send whole error thrown by Flutter, or describe the problem in Flutter.

Comment: Here it is -

Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 906:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 84:22                                                                                    <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1446:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 150:18                                        handleValue

Comment: P.S. I tried url_launcher too. It works perfectly, although I want to use http.

Comment: Try to change 127.0.0.1 to your local IP address, I don't know, if you're using emulator or not, but you can try it.

Comment: A few days ago, I uploaded my files on the web. It showed the same error message. Also, I'm running my project on the web not an emulator. Can this be the problem?

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't know, where can be problem.

Comment: (IMPORTANT) The problem is fixed. Actually, I was running my project on the web and the libraries didn't support the web then. When I tried on an app, it worked perfectly fine! Thanks for your time